# I am getting this SQLServerException: “The result set has no current row”. Not understanding

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to DB and execute the results from DB.
I'm getting the below error.

`Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row`.

```
public void getData() {
    try {           
        String query = "Select RetroRequestID, FirstName, LastName from RetroRequest_HMEarnOnOA where AccountNumber = 101930804";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Records from Database");
        while(rs.next());
        {
            String RetroRequestID = rs.getString("RetroRequestID");
            String FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
            String LastName = rs.getString("LastName");

            System.out.println("RetroRequestID: "+RetroRequestID+"   "+"FirstName: "+FirstName+"    "+"LastName: "+LastName);
        }   
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain that the raw query run on SQL Server directly would return any records?  My guess at an explanation is that the query is returning no rows.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: As error message says *The result set has no current row* may be your query is little bit wrong or there may be no value equal to your where clause, so the best thing to do is follow @TimBiegeleisen comment.

Comment: The Query returns the result.@TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

There is a semi-colon after the if statement in while which acting as an empty statement:

```
 while(rs.next()); {  // remove the semi-colon
```

This causes the cursor of the ResultSet to traverse all the rows until there is no one it's pointing, thereby causing the exception.